# How to make nested for loops with dynamically named `i` in bash

Tags: bash

So the following works to wrap the for loop and print out something for each item:

```
iterate() {
  local array=$1

  shift

  for i in $array; do
    $*
  done
}

iteratecallback() {
  echo item: $i
}

data=$(ls)
iterate "$data" iteratecallback
```

But what I would like to do is take the `echo item: $i` and make i into `echo item: $position` for top level, then `index` for next level nesting, then `i` for third level nesting, for example. Basically, be able to arbitrarily name these index variables *while passing them into the wrapping function*.

So for example, something like this:

```
iterate() {
  local customname=$1
  local array=$2

  shift

  for $customname in $array; do
    $*
  done
}

iteratecallback() {
  echo item: $position

  data2=$(ls)
  iterate index "$data2" iteratecallback2
}

iteratecallback2() {
  echo item: $index in $position
}

data=$(ls)
iterate position "$data" iteratecallback
```

Wondering how to do such a thing in Bash.

Comment: Note that you're not passing an array, you are passing a **string** that contains newlines. The `for` loop iterates over the **words** in that string, so if you have a filename that contains a space, you're not doing what you think you are.

Comment: You'll want to investigate "nameref" in the bash manual to truly reference a variable in the calling scope.